# Why does windows 10 not recognise my wifi adapter after Hyper-V uninstall

Tags: network-adapter, hyper-v, wifi-configuration

I have an Edimax AC600 USB wifi adapter (using the driver which comes with Windows 10).  I've had Windows 10 for a few months and it's been working fine.

The other night, I was trying out some VM software.  I initially tried Hyper-V, then VirtualBox.  I uninstalled the Hyper-V components from Windows, as you can't use 64-bit images with Virtualbox unless you do this ([Source](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/11/virtualbox-showing-32-bit-guest-versions-64-bit-host-os/#.Vo6uVxWLRaQ))

After a reboot, my wifi adapter stopped working.  It still shows up in Device Manager as a Network adapter (see image)

[image]

However, windows now has no 'wifi' area in its network settings, and no wireless connection in 'Network Connections', only the wired ethernet (see image)

[image]

I've tried disabled/re-enabling the device, and uninstalling/reinstalling the driver (which is the same Windows 10-supplied driver in any case).

I'm not sure how Windows has come to be in this state, but it seems likely to be related to the Hyper-V components, as that was the only significant change made at the time of the problem.

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this problem after a forced un- and reinstall of my WLAN driver. There was no WiFi adapter found, but drivers were there. 
My solution was to remove all the Hyper-V Virtual Switches. After I did that, the WiFi adapter appeared in my Network Connections. Those switches live between the Network Connections and the drivers, so it seems they hide the real adapter and create virtual ones.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear that in mind if I ever have to go through it again.  Ended up doing an OS reinstall :/

Answer (score 1):

I found a leftover network bridge under network connections that was using the WiFi adapter. deleting the bridge returned things to normal for me after having the same difficulties as mentioned here and elsewhere after removing Hyper-V.